# How to solve non-homogenous recurrence when non-homogenous part is a Constant?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$u(n)−3 u(n−1)+3 u(n−2)−u(n−3) = 17$

$U_n^{(c)} = (A +Bn+ Cn^2)*1^n$

$U_n^{(p)} = 17*1^n$

Is how far Ive gotten. I am unsure of what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The characteristic equation for the homogenous part is $$r^3-3r^2+3r-1=0$$ that is to say $(r-1)^3=0$. So, the solution of the homogenous equation is $$u_n=c_1+c_2 n+c_3 n^2$$ and then, the particular solution should be a polynomial of degree $3$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think I can. Would you mind further explaining what you mean by "the particular solution should be a polynomial of degree 3"? I had already figured out the solution to the homogeneous equation in my original post. Thanks

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe : Since you already have terms $n^0$, $n^1$, $n^2$ then for the complete equation you need terms in $n^3$.

Comment: Im sorry, but Im afraid I still dont quite get it. the terms $n^0, n^1, n^2$ refer to the solution of the homogenous equation correct? What exactly should be in terms of $n^3$?